# python and networkX keyerror

Tags: python

i have this problem in python, python keeps giving me an keyerror: weight

```
  g.add_edge(1,3,weight=2.5)
  g[1][2]['weight'] = 1.5
  for n1,n2,attr in g.edges(data=True):
    print n1,n2,attr['weight']
```

The output.

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-56-832c29e7e1db> in <module>()
         2 g[1][2]['weight'] = 1.5
         3 for n1,n2,attr in g.edges(data=True):
   ----> 4      print n1,n2,attr['weight']

   KeyError: 'weight'

   0 1
```

i dont know why weight gives me an error?

Comment: You assign ' g[1][2]['weight'] = 1.5' but try to acces like "g['weight']", what does return this "g.edges(data=True)" ??? If you try to do like print attr[n1][n2]['weight'] what do you get from that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you have some other edges in your graph, and haven't set the `weight` attribute for all of them. Try the following:

```
for n1,n2,attr in g.edges(data=True):
    print n1,n2,attr
```

See if `attr` contains a value for `weight` in every case.