# KeyError in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I am struggling with my graph algorithm using NetworkX and I keep getting the following error message. I know this question has been answered before ([python and networkX keyerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779247/python-and-networkx-keyerror)), but it seems that **I have a different problem**. My graph structure looks like this, I create seven DiGraphs but all have the same structure inlcuding three nodes and three dependencies:

```
## Network structure of Graph
for i in range(1):
    G_x = nx.DiGraph()
    G_x.add_node('x1', server = 5)
    G_x.add_node('x2', service = 3)
    G_x.add_node('x3', infrastructure = 2)
    G_x.add_edge('x1','x2', dependency = 0.6)
    G_x.add_edge('x1','x3', dependency = 0.6)
    G_x.add_edge('x2','x3', dependency = 0.3)

    G_a = nx.DiGraph()
    G_a.add_node('a1', server = 8)
    G_a.add_node('a2', service = 4)
    G_a.add_node('a3', infrastructure = 3)
    G_a.add_edge('a1','a2', dependency = 0.6)
    G_a.add_edge('a1','a3', dependency = 0.6)
    G_a.add_edge('a2','a3', dependency = 0.3)

    G_b = nx.DiGraph()
    G_b.add_node('b1', server = 12)
    G_b.add_node('b2', service = 5)
    G_b.add_node('b3', infrastructure = 3)
    G_b.add_edge('b1','b2', dependency = 0.6)
    G_b.add_edge('b1','b3', dependency = 0.6)
    G_b.add_edge('b2','b3', dependency = 0.3)

    G_c = nx.DiGraph()
    G_c.add_node('c1', server = 5)
    G_c.add_node('c2', service = 3)
    G_c.add_node('c3', infrastructure = 2)
    G_c.add_edge('c1','c2', dependency = 0.6)
    G_c.add_edge('c1','c3', dependency = 0.6)
    G_c.add_edge('c2','c3', dependency = 0.3)

    G_d = nx.DiGraph()
    G_d.add_node('d1', server = 9)
    G_d.add_node('d2', service = 4)
    G_d.add_node('d3', infrastructure = 2)
    G_d.add_edge('d1','d2', dependency = 0.6)
    G_d.add_edge('d1','d3', dependency = 0.6)
    G_d.add_edge('d2','d3', dependency = 0.3)

    G_e = nx.DiGraph()
    G_e.add_node('e1', server = 14)
    G_e.add_node('e2', service = 9)
    G_e.add_node('e3', infrastructure = 2)
    G_e.add_edge('e1','e2', dependency = 0.6)
    G_e.add_edge('e1','e3', dependency = 0.6)
    G_e.add_edge('e2','e3', dependency = 0.3)

    G_y = nx.DiGraph()
    G_y.add_node('y1', server = 3)
    G_y.add_node('y2', service = 1.5)
    G_y.add_node('y3', infrastructure = 0.5)
    G_y.add_edge('y1','y2', dependency = 0.6)
    G_y.add_edge('y1','y3', dependency = 0.6)
    G_y.add_edge('y2','y3', dependency = 0.3)
```

Now, I want to iterate through all my graphs, sample one random node and update its value in case of a "fail". Additionally, the node's neighbors will be affected too in case of a "spread":

```
# Select random node based on probability == 0.05/5.0%
sum_partial_fail = 0
affected_nodes_list = []
affected_node_values_list = []
for graph in [G_x, G_a, G_b, G_c, G_d, G_e, G_y]:
    random_node = random.sample(graph.nodes, 1)[0]
    print("Random_node: ", random_node)
    percentage_chance_of_failure = random.uniform(0, 1)
    print("Percentage chance of failure: ", percentage_chance_of_failure)
    attr = list(graph.nodes.data()[random_node].keys())[0]
    if percentage_chance_of_failure <= 0.3:
        old_node_value = graph.nodes[random_node][attr]
        print("Old node value: ", old_node_value)
        new_node_value = graph.nodes[random_node][attr] - 1
        print("New node value: ", new_node_value)
        if new_node_value < 0:
            nx.set_node_attributes(graph, {(random_node): {attr: 0}})
        for j in graph.neighbors(random_node):
            percentage_chance_of_spread = random.uniform(0, 1)
            print("Percentage chance of spread: ", percentage_chance_of_spread)
            if percentage_chance_of_spread >= 0.5:
#error          new_value = (1 - (graph[random_node][j]['dependency'] * (new_node_value / old_node_value)))\
                            * (graph.nodes[j][attr])
                nx.set_node_attributes(graph, {(j): {attr: new_value}})
                print("Random node attribute chance >0.5: ", random_node[attr])
```

All is working fine **except if the percentage_chance_of_spread is >= 0.5. Python is not returning my "new value" but gives me the following error message:"**

```
##Returned values
Random_node:  b1
Percentage chance of failure:  0.02705497047686123
Old node value:  12
New node value:  11
Percentage chance of spread:  0.6987620126722746
##Returned error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XXX", line 139, in <module>
    * graph.nodes[j][attr]
KeyError: 'service'
```

I really do not know what the problem is here, maybe someone can help me with this? Much appreciated!

Comment: Does it tell you which line the error occurs in?  Please give the entire error message.

Comment: I updated the error message.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to change the name of the attributes 'server', 'service', 'infrastructure' to 'value', meaning that every attribute has the name 'value' and then the algorithm worked. So I guess it has something to do with the different attribute names in the graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, not every node has an attribute `'service'`.  But some do.

If the `random_node` has that attribute, then at some point, you'll have `attr='service'`.  Then you loop `for j in graph.neighbors(random_node):`.

And in that case, if `percentage...>0.5`, you'll try to get `graph.nodes[j][attr]`, but `attr` is `'service'`.  I don't see any reason to expect that node `j` has that attribute just because `random_node` has it.